# How do you say: "I'm looking forward to meeting you" in Deutsch?

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german, vocabulary

I'm writing a script for a project in my german class, and it's supposed to be a phone call between a tour guide and a possible tourist. How can the tourist say (i am looking forward to meeting you) to the tour guide? I tried to find answers but google only confused me more. Please help if you can!

Comment: Show us what you found and why it confused you... This question can be easily answered with any online translator like google translate or deepl.com, tried both, both translations are 100% valid

Comment: Vote to close. https://www.deepl.com/translator-mobile#en/de/I'm%20looking%20forward%20to%20meeting%20you.

Comment: For some of these phrases the correct answer is that we just don't say that. A translation tool will not tell one that. Therefore I don't think that this should be closed just because a tool would give a translation.

Comment: @CarstenS I think you're right regarding some phrases. But for this one the translation of the tool is totally fine imo.

Comment: @Olafant, right, but how is one to know without asking?

Comment: @CarstenS But that's not the question here, or is it? OP is confused? About what? Btw. closing a question doesn't mean it shouldn't have been asked, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple translation would be:

> Ich freue mich, dich/Sie zu treffen

Note that depending on who you're talking to, you should be more polite, using the "Sie", which is the same in French, when you say "vous" instead of "tu". If you're talking to a friend use "du", but since the senctence kind of seems like you don't know that person, maybe you should stick with "Sie". Hope it doesn't confuse you.

I'm not entirely sure what exactly you want to say, but if you, for example, mean that you are looking forward to getting to know him, you would say:

> "Ich freue mich, dich/Sie kennenzulernen."

If you just want to say that you're excited for you to meet, you'd say:

> Ich freue mich auf unser Treffen

These would be some of my suggestions, being a native German speaker I know what I'm doing. If you had a different meaning in mind, let me know.